# Finding number of months between two dates including extra days?

Tags: java

i have a requirement where i need to find out number of months between two dates. i tried few examples but all are excluding number of extra days. please see in below example?

```
2010/03/22 -- fromdate
2010/05/30 -- todate
```

if we find diff between those dates then it is returning 2 months.here it is excluding 8 extra days. i need out put as **2.8**(`2 months and 8 days`). how can i achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: *"i tried few examples but all are excluding number of extra days."*  Try a lot of them, then report back with your best attempt (in code) & a specific question based on that attempt.  Also, please fix your shift key and use it at the start of every sentence.

Comment: java.util.Calendar would allow you to separate the different components (years, months, days). Still, in date arithmetic there are a number of special cases you need to define. f.ex. if from date is January 31st and to is February 28th, what would that be - one month, or zero months and 28 days? When you get this one defined, the other month issues should follow suit. The other place needing special attention is when the year rolls over.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for this:

```
LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate(2010, 3, 22);
LocalDate date2 = new LocalDate(2010, 5, 30);
PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.yearMonthDay().withoutYears();
Period difference = new Period(date1, date2, monthDay);
int months = difference.getMonths();
int days = difference.getDays();
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. but it is not calculating properly in case of 28 days in February. LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate(2010, 2, 28); 
          LocalDate date2 = new LocalDate(2010, 3, 31);  in above example it should not return any difference in days. but it is showing days difference as 3. please help me.

Comment: @user1016403: Why should it not show a difference in days? If you add one month to February 28th, you get to March 28th... at which point if you add another three days, you get to March 31st. If that isn't your desired behaviour, you'll need to be more specific about your *precise* requirements - which I suspect you may find tricky.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. what i mean is february month will have only 28 days. so from feb 28 to march 31st is not a single month? please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: @user1016403: Well it depends on how you're measuring it. Date and time arithmetic is hard to pin down. But adding a month and then adding 3 days to February 28th gets to March 31st, so I can't see that the Joda Time answer can be seen as "wrong" really. If you have clear ideas about your exact requirements, you should state those with *lots* of examples.

Comment: I think the issue is adding one month. That month would be March and there are 31 days. So adding one month to it would get you to March 31st, not March 28th, because that is not adding 1 full month of march, but only adding 28 days of March. 28 days != 1 full month of March.

Comment: @user1567291 But then there are other issues if you add "5 days and 2 months" which months are you adding, if you view each month as a different amount? Basically there are different rules you can come up with, but no one "right" way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff) for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change this method little to get that extra days.
/**
 * Gets number of months between two dates. 
 * <p>Months are calculated as following:</p>
 * <p>After calculating number of months from years and months from two dates,
 * if there are still any extra days, it will be considered as one more month.
 * For ex, Months between 2012-01-01 and 2013-02-06 will be 14 as 
 * Total Months = Months from year difference are 12 + Difference between months in dates is 1  
 * + one month since day 06 in enddate is greater than day 01 in startDate.
 * </p>
 * @param startDate
 * @param endDate
 * @return
 */
public static int getMonthsBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate)
{
    if(startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime())
    {
        Date temp = startDate;
        startDate = endDate;
        endDate = temp;
    }
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
    Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCalendar.setTime(endDate);

    int yearDiff = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)- startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthsBetween = endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)-startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) +12*yearDiff;

    if(endCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) >= startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        monthsBetween = monthsBetween + 1;
    return monthsBetween;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
 org.joda.time.Month#monthsBetween(start, end)
```

Comment: this will only  return the number of whole months between the two specified datetimes. OP asked for month including extra days.